# decision tree prediction in R uses the id to influence the prediction

Tags: r, decision-tree

I'm using C50 library to try and predict the attendance for next years' graduation however my tree shows the ID as part of the prediction! when i take it out my tree becomes one node (level) only .. any suggestions will be highly appreciated

part of the Dataset (JSON):

```
{"id":"50","name":"James Charlie","faculty":"Science","degree":"Bachelor degree","course":"Sport Science","attend":"No","year":"2016"},
```

full dataset/Student object: [git repo](https://github.com/myCatIsLost/question)

R script:

```
con=dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'root', password = '', dbname='students', host = 'localhost') dbListTables(con) Student <- dbReadTable(con, 'students') rows <- nrow(Student)

    Student$attend <- as.factor(Student$attend) Student$year <- as.factor(Student$year) 
Student$faculty <- as.factor(Student$faculty) 
Student$course <- as.factor(Student$course) 
Student 
dim(Student) 
summary(Student)

str(Student)
    Student <- Student[-2]
    dim(Student)

str(Student)

set.seed(1234)
Student_rand <- Student[order(runif(719)), ] #randomize the data
Student_train <- Student_rand[1:400, ] #split data/train data to predect the test
Student_test  <- Student_rand[401:719, ] #validation for train prediction
summary(Student_train)


prop.table(table(Student_train$attend))#propability for prediction
prop.table(table(Student_test$attend))

Student_model <- C5.0(Student_train[,-5],Student_train$attend)

summary(Student_model)

Student_model
summary(Student_model)
jpeg("tree.jpg")
plot(Student_model)
dev.off()

Student_model$predictors
Student_model$trials
Student_model$tree
summary(Student_model)

Student_pred <- predict(Student_model, Student_test,type="class")

table(Student_test$attend ,Student_pred)
CrossTable(Student_pred, Student_test$attend,
           prop.chisq = FALSE, prop.c = FALSE, prop.r = FALSE,
           dnn = c('predicted default', 'actual default'))
```

and finally the tree:
[image]

**the first thing I tried was removing the id and i got the following error:

Error in partysplit(varid = as.integer(i), index = index, info = k, prob = NULL) *

> :    minimum of ‘index’ is not equal to 1 In addition: Warning
>   message: In min(index, na.rm = TRUE) :   no non-missing arguments to
>   min; returning Inf

*

then i tried and added a random column which cause the prediction to use that random column as an inference..**

Comment: Try making the ID the row names instead of a column of its own

Comment: If you need further help, make an example data set available (use `dput` on Student or `head(Student, 30)` if you have many observations). The 4 lines of json are insufficient to allow us to replicate your problem.

Comment: hello there, I added it as a sample so people will know what is the dataset i'm working with..  i will attach it in the question :)

Comment: Your question implies you have an R object named `Student`. Instead of posting SQL/JSON code in your Github version of the data, why not use dput or dump to create an ASCII version of the actual R structure. Or you could post the R code that was used to read from that URL.

Comment: @42- i attach the object in the git directory/ and the full R code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied the structure and assigned to `Student`. The original dataframe which retains the association of name and id showed that there were many repeats of hte name variable:

```
str(Student[2])
#'data.frame':  724 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ name: chr  "Jill Austin" "David Beckham" "Chris Evans" "Sheldon Cooper" ...
length(table(Student[2]))
#[1] 201
```

Then I looked at the repeatingness in the first 165 ids and they had a very low probability if the id were less than 165:

```
length(table(Student[1:164, 2]))
[1] 163
```

So define a variable that flags repeats:

```
 Student$IsRepeated <- ave( Student$name, Student$name, FUN=length) > 1
```

And it then turns out that  "name.repeatingness" was associated with attendance after the other predictors are taken into account.

```
> with( Student, table( attend, IsRepeated ) )
      IsRepeated
attend FALSE TRUE
   No     50  259
   Yes    59  356   # so nothing dramatic here, but try other predictors as well
```

First I looked at output of:

```
 with( Student, table(attend, year, IsRepeated , faculty) )
```

Kind of long, so I noticed that the Science and Engineering groups were somewhat different:

```
  with( Student, table(attend, year, IsRepeated , fac_EorS=faculty %in% c("Engineering", "Science") ) )
, , IsRepeated = FALSE, fac_EorS = FALSE

      year
attend 2015 2016 2017 2018
   No     0    0    0   10
   Yes    0    0    0   16

, , IsRepeated = TRUE, fac_EorS = FALSE

      year
attend 2015 2016 2017 2018
   No     9    9    9  131
   Yes   37   17   17  113

, , IsRepeated = FALSE, fac_EorS = TRUE

      year
attend 2015 2016 2017 2018
   No     0    0    1   39
   Yes    1    0    0   42

, , IsRepeated = TRUE, fac_EorS = TRUE

      year
attend 2015 2016 2017 2018
   No    34   34   33    0   # also shows how the `date` became the 2nd split
   Yes   45   32   32   63
```

Comment: thank you so much for replaying, the data i used is just a dummy data that i built using 300 record then i realized that i needed more records so i duplicated it with different courses/attendance/years. when i built my model i took out the name attribute so it won't effect the prediction results.. were you be able to plot the tree itself? thank you again :)

Comment: Nope; didn't even try. I just used your image to look at the split point in IDs.